# Can a warning be implemented when the "Pending Edit Queue" is full?

Tags: feature-request, editing, suggested-edits

My Reputation isn't high enough yet to edit questions/answers without moderator review. Therefore, any edits I do are entered into a queue for these pending edits. I'm aware of this and accepting of it.

However, I'm not monitoring this queue regularly, and I'm not keeping a mental record of how many are in the queue. Recently, I've discovered that there's a limit to how many I'm allowed to have in the queue before editing more. Once again, I'm ok with this.

But the problem I have is that **I don't know that the queue is full until after I've spent time editing** and then clicking *Submit*. When doing so, I get the following error message:

```
You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved.
```

This might go without saying, but this is a bit frustrating after having spent time editing.

Can the application be changed so that either a warning is presented when the queue is full or that the *Edit* button is blocked from clicking? Ideally, I'd recommend both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the message. It's not the Suggested edits queue that is full, which in fact has only 5 suggested edits at the moment.

It's that you, as a user with less than 2000 reputation points, cannot have more than 5 edits pending. Just wait a bit and your pending edits will be handled by community reviewers and you will be able to suggest edits again.

The reasoning for this limit is *"to limit the damage someone can do with blasting the review queue with minor edit suggestions"*, as you can read in [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits).
To keep track of your pending edits, you can go to your profile → *Activity* → *All actions* → *Suggestions* or click [this link](https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and see how many pending edits you have (see the following screenshot from my profile, though I don't have any pending edits at the moment).

> [image: Suggestions section in my profile]

As for your suggestion to get a warning or have the *Edit* button disabled when you have reached the 5 suggested edits limit, you need to ask for it in [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com), since it's a feature that should be implemented network-wide, if it gets accepted.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it correctly. I'm not saying that the entire Suggested Edits queue is full. I'm saying MY suggested edits queue is full, & I'm unaware it's full until I've edited the 6th suggestion & attempted to submit it. At that point, I get the warning, but I've already spent time editing. I have no problem with it being limited to 5. I have no problem waiting until they're reviewed. I just would like to know it's full before I blindly edit another. Most of the time, I'm not editing a bunch in a row, so I'm not keeping track of how many I've edited and how many have been reviewed.

Comment: Yes, I understand your frustration. As I said in my answer, such a feature must be requested at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), it cannot implement it in Ask Ubuntu only. If you do make a feature request there, please also drop a link here, so that me and other users that find it useful can upvote it. In the meantime, to keep track of your pending edits, you can go to your profile -> *Activity* -> *All  actions* -> *Suggestions* and see how many pending edits you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll submit the feature request soon.